# GRPC error log (Android Studio)

Tags: android, ubuntu-16.04, logcat, grpc, error-log

From some time I am getting a very strange error log, that makes no sense since I don`t use GRPC in my project.

The log is spamming each second in the logcat as follows:

`...
05-16 10:53:13.249 24321-24368/my.package E/GRPC: tcp_client_posix.c:173] failed to connect to 'ipv4:127.0.0.1:12389': socket error: connection refused
05-16 10:53:14.249 24321-24368/my.package E/GRPC: tcp_client_posix.c:173] failed to connect to 'ipv4:127.0.0.1:12389': socket error: connection refused
05-16 10:53:15.254 24321-24367/my.package E/GRPC: tcp_client_posix.c:173] failed to connect to 'ipv4:127.0.0.1:12389': socket error: connection refused
...`

As this is not making my app crash or lag it is very unpleasant when looking into the logcat.

I suspect that it has something to do with my OS - ubuntu 16.04 LTS because this error log is not present when the project is run on Windows.

The problem is not device related since I tried with many devices and I always see it.

If you need any more info I will provide it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this error comes during test the app in emulator device or real device?

Comment: On a real device and thanks for the hint. After further investigation, we found out that this error is more Ubuntu related. I tried with many phones and the error log is always showing. After starting the same project on Windows there was no such error log. So maybe it has something to do with my computer`s OS.

Comment: Yes, you right. It is may be because of proxyPort or port settings which connects the device/emulator to pc.

Comment: As a sanity check, are you sure there is actually a server listening on port 12389?  Also, is the server listening both on the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the new Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1 and enabled **Advanced profiling** under **Android profiler** that could be the cause.

Try to open the Run/Debug configurations for your app module (usually called "app") clicking on the app module ("app" in the screenshot) spinner and selecting **Edit configurations** in the dropdown menu.

[image]

Then select your app module and under **Profiling** tab uncheck **Enable advanced profiling**

[image: Run/Debug configurations]

Rebuild your app and it should be ok.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now that I know the issue I remember I enabled it a while ago to try the new Android Profiler features and really that was about the time when this logs started showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

- In **`File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy`** check settings and select **`No proxy`**.

after that Clean Project > Rebuild Project then run and check.

Comment: Thank you, but this(No proxy) is the selected option right now.

Comment: Then you are right its problem because of OS. It is not providing proper port or address to emulator/device. I have seen that but don't remember how I solved that. Now I have new laptop intel i5 with 8GB RAM and in which I have installed java (check and set java path), virtualBox, and then Android Studio one-by-one and after that I haven't seen any warning for that. Hope, you will find solution.